# how to use sorting indices to sort integers from a structure array in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that asks the user what element of a structure to sort by, and then prints the sorted list. I'm using a separate array (sorting index) to sort the elements without changing the structure itself, but can't get the function to actually sort the elements. I'm using nested for loops to do the sorting.

```
typedef struct  {
    unsigned long term;
    unsigned long id_num;
    char dept[5];
    int crs_num;
} crsinfo_t;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    crsinfo_t info[50];
    i = 50;
    /* I read the info in from a file but just didn't include that bit*/
    sort(i, info);

    return(0);
}


void sort(int i, crsinfo_t info[50])
{
    int sorter[50];
    int holder = 0;
    int f, j, k, m, n;

    for (f=0; f<=i; f++){
        sorter[f] = f;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        for (k = j+1; k < i; k++) {
            if (info[j].term <= info[k].term) {
                holder = sorter[j];
                sorter[j] = sorter[k];
                sorter[k] = holder;
            }
        }
    }

    for (m=0; m<i; m++)
    {
        printf("%lu %lu %s %2d \n", info[sorter[m]].term), 
        info[sorter[m]].id_num, info[sorter[m]].dept, 
        info[sorter[m]].crs_num}
    }
}
```

It should print the list of all the elements sorted based on `term` in ascending order, but the numbers are still randomly organized (although different from the original file).

Comment: Because of `f<=i`, your program end up accessing `sorter` array beyond its size - `sorter[f]`.

Answer (score 1):

> It should print the list of all the elements with the term sorted in ascending order....

Though, the core logic of your code is correct but it will sort in descending order and not ascending order due to `<=` in this statement:

```
if (info[j].term <= info[k].term) {
                 ^^
```

If you want to sort in ascending order, use `>` operator.

In this loop,

```
for (f=0; f<=i; f++){
    sorter[f] = f;
}
```

your program is accessing array `sorter` beyond its limit. The size of `sorter` array is `50`, indexed from `0` to `49` and because of loop condition `f<=i` it ends up accessing `sorter[50]` which is beyond the size of array.

Look at the `printf(...` in the last loop:

```
for (m=0; m<i; m++)
   { printf("%lu %lu %s %2d \n", info[sorter[m]].term), 
     info[sorter[m]].id_num, info[sorter[m]].dept, 
   info[sorter[m]].crs_num}
```

Isn't the compiler giving error on this statement? The `)` is wrongly placed. Moreover, no semicolon at the end of `printf` statement.

It should be:

```
for (m=0; m<i; m++)
{ 
    printf("%lu %lu %s %2d \n", info[sorter[m]].term, 
                                info[sorter[m]].id_num, 
                                info[sorter[m]].dept, 
                                info[sorter[m]].crs_num);
}
```

Sample code with taking `5` hardcoded value of `crsinfo_t` struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        unsigned long term;
        unsigned long id_num;
        char dept[5];
        int crs_num;
} crsinfo_t;

void sort(int i, crsinfo_t info[5]);

int main(void) {
        int i;
        crsinfo_t info[5] = {{4, 2, "abc", 7}, {5, 2, "def", 9}, {8, 0, "ghi", 9}, {3, 8, "jkl", 4}, {1, 3, "mno", 4}};
        i = 5;
        sort(i, info);
        return 0;
}

void sort(int i, crsinfo_t info[5]) {
        int sorter[5];
        int holder = 0;
        int f, j, k, m;

        for (f = 0; f < i; f++){
                sorter[f] = f;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                for (k = j + 1; k < i; k++) {
                        if (info[j].term > info[k].term) {
                                holder = sorter[j];
                                sorter[j] = sorter[k];
                                sorter[k] = holder;
                        }
                }
        }

        for (m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                printf("%lu %lu %s %2d \n", info[sorter[m]].term,
                                                info[sorter[m]].id_num,
                                                info[sorter[m]].dept,
                                                info[sorter[m]].crs_num);
        }
}
```

Output:
Sorted in ascending order based on `term` member of struct `crsinfo_t`.

```
#  ./a.out
1 3 mno  4 
3 8 jkl  4 
4 2 abc  7 
5 2 def  9 
8 0 ghi  9
```